# Fedora 20 : Launch vlc video at startup

Tags: cron, vlc, fedora20

I would like to launch a video with VLC in fedora 20 for atm project.

I already succeed to get the right command line in crontab

@reboot vlc -vvv --loop --fullscreen video_file

but i think vlc is launching & crashing because X server is not totally launched.

Is there an option to make a wait in cron or should i cron a bash script with a timeout before to launch VLC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

( vlc requires an x server to be launched , so you to give it your local x server ip : :0 )

here is the command line :

```
 @reboot DISPLAY=:0 vlc -vvv --loop --fullscreen video_file
```

and everything is fine